# libc6 package breaks existing packages on air gapped server

Tags: ubuntu, apt, libc, deb

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 amd64 and trying to upgrade libc6 package on my air gapped server.
I have my own apt repositories, where i store all the packages i download. I downloaded the latest version which is 2.37-7 and all of the latest dependencies, and when I try upgrading using `sudo apt upgrade libc6`, I get the error:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.32) but 2.37-7 is to be installed libc6: Breaks: firefox (< 91~) but 82.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed Breaks: locales (< 2.37) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed`

I assume I need to download later versions of libc-bin, but this package is a bit sensetive, and I want to know if there is a safe way to do this, and also if there is a way to automatically download al the dependencies.
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you need also a new `locales` package, do you have it on your local repo?

Comment: Yes I have a 2.31-0ubuntu9.1, the one from the error

Comment: you need `2.37-7` - a version that matches the libc version (both packages are built from the same source - and need to match)

Comment: any idea where can i see all the libraries i will need to update

Comment: You should have a local full offline mirror. IMHO what you are trying to do, is not really the way `apt` is intended to be used. See this: https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-apt-repository-server-ubuntu/  - basically you are looking for `apt-mirror`.

I admit - fully untested answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should have a fully local offline apt mirror, and not a set of package. Install `apt-mirror` on a connected machine, create a full mirror - and then use it on the air gapped machine.

See: https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-apt-repository-server-ubuntu/